# how to translate the properties of an object in data table

Tags: angular, object, datatables, ngx-translate

I currently use the material data table and the ngx-trnslate library

I manage to iterate on an object in a data table, but the problem is that I only have to translate properties.

I’ve seen the code that allows you to iterate on an object like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of (identy| keyvalue)">
      <td>{{ i.key }}</td>
      <td>{{ i.value }}</td>
   </tr>
```

Here is my object, it's a fake, values will be provided by the server later

```
  identity = {
      prenom: "toto",
      nom: "titi"
    }
```

But how can I translate the key here in my json files ?

```
   "PROPERTIES":
    {
        "prenom": "surname",
        "nom": "name"
    },
```

I tried to use the get observable like this:

```
this.translate.get(
        ['PROPERTIES.prenom', 'PROPERTIES.nom'])
        .subscribe(val => {
          this.tradPrenom = val['PROP.prenom'];
          this.tradNom = val['PROP.nom'];
        });
```

I’ve been struggling with this for a few hours without finding any solutions. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the translation tag in your template (note the `.` after `PROPERTIES`)

```html
<tr *ngFor="let i of (identy| keyvalue)">
      <td>{{ "PROPERTIES." + i.key | translate }}</td>
      <td>{{ i.value }}</td>
   </tr>
```

This will make your template look for `"PROPERTIES.prenom"` and `"PROPERTIES.nom"`